# Windows 8.1 Does not Sleep, but shuts down when lid is closed

Tags: windows

So, after installing the Windows 8.1 update to my Dell laptop that shipped with Windows 8, I have had an issue that is rather annoying.  Before installing the update, I was able to shut the lid and later open it with everything being exactly like it was when I shut it. Now, post update, it seems that the operating system shuts down completely when the lid closes, and when it is opened it will do a total reboot.  I have explored all power options and have switched from 'do nothing' to 'sleep' to 'hibernate', all with the same results.  This is extremely annoying as I often need to relocate and continue working. If I shut the lid for safe transport I am faced with a lengthy reboot and reopening programs I had been using minutes before.  Please advise.  Thank you for your input....

Comment: try disabling IPV6 , uncheck IPV6 from ethernet properties, set the power button and lid action as sleep.

Comment: I had this issue problem with my surface pro 2. Turned out it was my USB to DVI adapter software/driver. Only when i uninstalled that software did the surface start to function properly again.

Comment: Same problem occurring on HP Folio 9480m, shipped with 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Power options's values changes from one power plan(power saver, high performance etc.) to another. Maybe you've changed one power plan's settings, but your laptop is actually running with another power plan. Just check it out.

Comment: I have the same issue. Every plan is set to sleep whether on battery or plugged in. And these are the out of the box plans. I haven't customized them or created new ones.